# problem in persisting the object in oneToMany and manyToOne relationship in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring, persistence

I have one doubt which is related to hibernate ... if I have following scenerio

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CONTINENT")
public class Continent {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;


private String name;


@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "CONTI_ID")
private Set<Country> countries;
public Continent() {

}
```

Following is my Country class

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="COUNTRY")
    public class Country {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        //@Column(name="CTRY_ID")
        private Integer id;

        @Column(name="CTRY_NAME")
        private String name;

        private int area;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "CONTI_ID")
        private Continent continent;

        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        private LanguageSpoken lang;
}
```

I am trying to perform following

```
updateCountry(){
Continent c1 = new Continent();
Country c = getNewCountry(c1);
c.setArea("berlin");
continentDao.update(c1);// **will child's location be set in db????**
c.getId().equals(1);//**If above questions answer is yes then why it throws null pointer exception**
}


getNewCountry(c1){
Country c = new Country();
c.setName("germany");
c1.getCountry().add(c);
continentDao.update(c1);
}
```

Can some one please help me in understanding the questions in comments
why I am getting Null Pointer at this line
c.getId()

Comment: Why is it throwing NPE? Is c null? If c is null, why is an NPE not thrown in the line c.setArea("berlin");

Comment: sorry my mistake i updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

In a bidirectional relationship, you have to wire both sides of the relationship. Here, you have wired only one side

```
c1.getCountry().add(c);
```

You also need to wire the reverse relationship, i.e.

```
c.setContinent(c1);
```

Additionally, c.getId() might be null because you have set it to a GeneratedValue and it hasn't been persisted yet. So wire both sides of the relationship.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply !! the problem I am having is I need id of the child and Id of child's parent in current session. maintaining the mapping through the way you suggested works well for all parameters but not for ID. since ID of the child is created only on persisting the child, it is not present in object graph. How can i perform a fetch on id in same session.??

Answer (score 1):

In any bi-directional relationship you should chose one side to be the owning side.  This is done by setting the "mappedBy" attribute.  Generally that would be done on the one-to-many side (Continent in your case).  With that mapping correct you will avoid any contention between the country and the continent when saving.

The second part of the problem is exactly what rationalSpring mentioned.  Modifying one side of a bi-directional relationship and saving it will update the record in the database, but it will not update any object graphs you already have loaded.  For this reason it's usually best to have a service method that takes care of managing the object graph.  In your case, it would take care of making sure the bi-directional link between country and continent are set correctly, then you would save the owning side of the relationship.

Comment: thanks digitaljoel but the problem i am facing is related to fetching Id of the child object, which is not present currently in object graph.